# Did the writer of Tarzan ever state Jungle Book as inspiration?

Tags: tarzan, the-jungle-book

Did the writer of the original version of Tarzan ever say if he was inspired by Kipling's Jungle Book?

While there are a number of differences between the 2, the main story - boy raised by animals in a jungle, learns to communicate with these animals and serves as there protector - is remarkably similar.

Comment: Some clarification: The creator of Tarzan was Edgar Rice Burroughs, who published Tarzan of the Apes in 1912, some 18 years after Rudyard Kipling published The Jungle Book. A quick Google brings up stories about Burroughs both admitting and denying Jungle Book as his inspiration, so maybe someone who's read up on Tarzan has an authoritative response.

Comment: Burroughs was often heavily inspired by other writers. His novel *The Mad King* is for instance a clear ripoff of *The Prisoner of Zenda*, and *A Princess of Mars* leans a lot on Edwin Arnold's *Gulliver of Mars*. So I think it is likley that *Tarzan of the Apes* was influenced by *The Jungle Book*.

Comment: Yes, but Tarzan has no cross-dressing bears! (Oops, think I just revealed that I've only seen the Disney animated movie...).

Comment: When asked if he liked Kipling, Burroughs answered "I don't know,. I've never kippled, before."

Comment: "Raised by animals" dates back to Romulus and Remus or even earlier. While it's entirely possible that The Jungle Book was Burroughs' direct inspiration, both stories were drawing on long established tropes.

Comment: There's an entire essay (with a dozen quotes and references) [here](https://books.google.se/books?id=HH6PCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT20&lpg=PT20&dq=burroughs+inspiration+%22romulus+and+remus%22&source=bl&ots=oM67j504ld&sig=ACfU3U1kkJQCnOFFhye2DtymlyGiWipJ-w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjYs4Tc_IbpAhUyyKYKHaKFBs0Q6AEwD3oECBEQAQ#v=onepage&q=burroughs%20inspiration%20%22romulus%20and%20remus%22&f=false). I'm sure an answer could be made out of this, but it would be loooong. In short, ERB denied a direct link, but admitted to generic inspiration.

Comment: Kipling certainly thought so. He accused ERB of crafting a "jazzed up" version of Mowgli; https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.525263/page/n235/mode/2up/search/tarzan